# How would you change the chirality of a compound such that (S,R) becomes (S,S)?

Tags: chirality

How would you change the chirality of a compound such that (S,R) becomes (S,S)? That is how would you synthesise a compound from its diastereomer?

Comment: Can you make this question a bit more concrete? Both (S,R) and (S,S) forms of a molecule are diastereomers as they have more than one stereocenter. Beyond regioselective stereoinversion, this question doesn't really have a specific answer.

Comment: You mean you want me to add an example of particular significance to me?

Comment: @BrentonHorne - An example would be helpful. The methods of changing a chirality center's configuration vary significantly in ease and reagents by functional group.